# Dumpper and Jumpstart for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux, wps

I try Reaver, but takes too long and not working for me. Dumpper and jumpstart in this [article](http://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/2mt3wr/step_by_step_guide_to_using_winpcap_dumpper_and/) worked for me, is there any equivalent for GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must have used the kali version of reaver that support WPS Pixie Dust Attack  (you can download it from [here](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/r/reaver/))

Comment: To be exactly an equivalente you must satisfy two things. To have the default PINS (up to 4), and to have the WPS pairing method. A plus could be to export the KEY from profiles. Dumpper is indeed a very nice piece of software. Reaver does the work, but by default it just tries FOREVER the same key like dumb, blocking the Access.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and vm windows on the linux machine and then get dumpper on it or you could find something like a windows emulator for linux.

Comment: While this might technically work, this doesn't really address OPs question of 'is there an equivalent?'